# Double calculates floating numbers wrong

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm currently working on a project which contains the calculation of certain values on screen:

```
double calculatedValue;
double calculatedValue2;
private JTextField firstUnity;
private JTextField secondUnity;
firstUnity = new JTextField();
firstUnity.setEditable(false);
secondUnity = new JTextField();
secondUnity.setEditable(false);
add(firstUnity);
add(secondUnity);

public void calculate(){
    calculatedValue = 10/2.5;
    calculatedValue2 = 10/2.55;
    firstUnity.setText(String.valueOf(calculatedValue));
    secondUnity.setText(String.valueOf(calculatedValue2));
}
```

For `firstUnity` the TextField shows `4` as expected.
Unfortunately `secondUnity` shows `"5686274509807"`.

Can someone explain to me what could be the reason for this interpretation?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think its the problem with the size of `JTextField`. `3.921` is not visible for `3.9215686274509807`

Answer (score 5):

Your `JTextField` is too short to display the `double`. You can fix this by either ensuring that the label is wide enough, or by decreasing the number of decimal places displayed using a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
public static final DecimalFormat DISPLAY_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

public void calculate(){
    calculatedValue = 10/2.5;
    calculatedValue2 = 10/2.55;
    firstUnity.setText(FORMAT.format(calculatedValue));
    secondUnity.setText(FORMAT.format(calculatedValue2));
}
```

You can adjust the number of decimal places shown by increasing/decreasing the number of `#` characters in the `DecimalFormat` constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Pretty obvious mistake and a perfect solution

Answer (score 4):

The answer of calculatedValue2 = 3.9215686274509807.
See those last numbers matches your 'wrong answer'?

I think your textfield is not wide enough to show the whole answer.
Try to change the size of the textfield.